# Custom filesize format with Python Humanize?

Tags: python

I'm using the Python [Humanize module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/humanize) to format some filesize info. The module defaults to one decimal place, is there a way to return values with a different number of decimal places?

This is the default:

```
>>> humanize.naturalsize(12345678)
'12.3 MB'
```

Is there a way to get:  `12.35 MB` or `12 MB` using this module?

Comment: Why not just use normal print command formatting for decimal places ?

Comment: Convenience and consistency. I'm using the library in other places and it's a nice timesaver. Also, I'm feeding in various byte sizes with other suffixes (KB, GB, etc).

Answer (score 4):

No, this is not possible. The format specifier, `%.1f`, is hard coded:
https://github.com/jmoiron/humanize/blob/master/humanize/filesize.py#L33-L38

**EDIT**:
[joemaller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/503463/joemaller) just submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/jmoiron/humanize/pull/13) for this functionality.

Comment: pull request was merged, not sure when it'll be sucked into Pypi